# Better algorithm for shortening English words

Tags: algorithm, text, nlp

I have some unique codes that are generated from strings (ex: website host names) in various independent components of my application.

These codes are meant to be used by machines only so i would like to keep them as short as possible.

The below algorithm would be applied to every word in the string. The output words would be concatenated with a dash to generate the unique code.

```
The current algorithm I have used:

 - Skip word if length is less than 6

 - Leave first character as is

 - Remove every wowel in the word from the second character onwards
```

1. architectural digest eu => archtctrl-dgst-eu
2. arizona foothills magazine => arzn-fthlls-mgzn

Is there a better way to shorten an English word leaving it as recognisable as possible to a human reader?

The output should be deterministic and produce the same shortened version whenever it is run on the same input.

A good algorithm should also minimise the number of clashes for similarly spelt words.

Answer (score 2):

> I have some unique codes that are generated from strings

I am afraid that is not true. There are many English words that will reduce to the same 'code word' when stripped of their vowels. For example, 'leaving' -> 'living' Given, this is fairly rare, it could still cause issues.

How important is it that these 'code words' remain human-readable if as you say, they are meant to be used by machines only? If its not that important, I'd suggest looking into some simpler compression algorithms like [Huffman Coding](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Huffman_coding) or [LZW Compression](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch). Then if the user needs to see the translation of the code word, just uncompress it.

If you must keep it human-readable, I'm not sure that there is much more you can do to shorten it. You could take a look at specific latin + greek roots, and determine if you can shorten those any more by hand, and then just substitute those out automatically.

Alternatively, you could turn to a phonetic approach. Automatically search the pronunciation of the word, and then see if that is any shorter (or itself can be compressed, taking 'cee' to 'C', or 'kay' to 'K'). This would be much more time and CPU intensive, but its still an option if you really, really need short but yet readable codes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Compression is a good option but unreadable, Also I dont ever need to reverse the code. Agree that phonetic approach is very heavy. Need to find a middle ground. :) Also worth noting that when multiple words are present the chance of a clash will reduce.

Answer (score 2):

What you're generating sounds like what's called a ["slug"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug). There are many libraries to handle this for blogs or site generators that should suit your purposes. Here's a usage example from a Python library called [slugify](https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify):

```
txt = "___This is a test ---"
r = slugify(txt)
self.assertEqual(r, "this-is-a-test")
```

Slug libraries generally work like this:

1. replacing non-ascii linguistic characters via a mapping (ex: `影師嗎 -> ying-shi-ma`)
2. replace accented latin letters with ascii equivalents via a mapping (ex: `C'est déjà l'été. -> c-est-deja-l-ete`)
3. remove beginning and trailing spaces/punctuation
4. convert remaining spaces and punctuation to dashes, collapsing multiple dashes in a row to a single dash

If you want to make slugs shorter you could remove vowels or, more simply, use a maximum length.